# Recaptcha v3 Pagespeed issues : how to defer?

Tags: php, recaptcha, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, recaptcha-v3

I am using Recaptcha on most of my pages (wordpress blog with WP-Forms plugin - [exemple here](https://www.projethomestudio.fr/microphones-studio/)).

When running a Google Pagespeed Insights audit, the audit is telling me that "…Trd6gj1dh…/recaptcha__en.js" is loading 2 times and is not used.

I have deferred the script like this :
`<script type='text/javascript' **defer async="async"** src='https://www.google.com/**recaptcha/api.js**?render=6LeDg6MbAAAAACFP_azCkEF4wG_jq1Vy-QXu42ik' id='wpforms-recaptcha-js'></script>`

However, the script name is different (api.js vs. recaptcha__en.js). Therefore I don't understand how to defer the recaptcha__en.js as well. How to do it ?